# About variational calculus conmutative

Tags: calculus-of-variations, variational-analysis

I need some help with the development of an expression, it is:
$$\delta\left\{\frac{\partial^3F(q^1,q^2,t)}{\partial t\partial q^1 \partial q^2}\right\}$$

with each of $q^1,q^2$ are functions of $t$. I want to know this is expression is equal to...

In the other hand, can the variational $\delta$ operator conmute with the derivate ($d/dt$) and partial derivate ($\partial/\partial t$) operators?. I'm a newbie, please don't be rude... Thanks in advance...

Any book to search for?

Comment: Zwiebach has an excellent discussion of precisely this crucially important point in his book on string theory. I will hunt out the reference and add it here.

Comment: Thank's man, I wait for it! :)

Comment: Section 5.3 of Zwiebach "a first course in string theory" essentially answers your question

Comment: If this is a Lagrangian treatment it changes the sense of this caculus?

Comment: I don't see why the results of the book should be limited to a Lagrangian philosophy. It's just that application to Lagrangian mechanics is a special case of your more general question.